# Symfony translation in custom service not working

Tags: php, symfony, service, translation

I had a custom service and the translation inside it doesn't work.
Symfony Version 3.2.3

Constructor:

```
public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator){
    $this->translator = $translator;
}
```

Method:

```
public function iConvertDateTimeString(){
     ...
if ($dateTime === false) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
        $this->translator->trans(
            'elasticsearch.exception.service.date.wrong_format'
        ),
        1488549113
    );
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    elastic_search.elasticsearch:
        class: MyCompany\ElasticSearchBundle\Services\ElasticSearchService
        arguments: [ "@translator" ]
```

exceptions.de_DE.yml:

```
elasticsearch:
    exception:
        service:
            date:
                wrong_format: Der DateTime String hat das falsche Format. Benutze 'Y-m-d H:i:s' oder 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'.
```

Output:

```
elasticsearch.exception.service.date.wrong_format
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

Whats the problem? Allready cleared the cache for prod and dev with warm-up after it. Translation are found and displayed in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$this->translator->trans(
        'elasticsearch.exception.service.date.wrong_format'
)
```

With

```
$this->translator->trans(
        'elasticsearch.exception.service.date.wrong_format', array(), 'exceptions'
)
```

Comment: I edited mine, you have to set the domain : see here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation.html#using-message-domains

Comment: Thanks for your fast help :) It works. I will accept your answer in a few minutes.